# Firefox: Width in % issue

Tags: html, css, firefox, styles

I cant figure out why the following would work on Internet Explorer and Chrome, but not Firefox. It basically has not effect on Firefox:

```
<fieldset style="width:30%;">
```

Thanks,

Comment: ... It works fine on Firefox. Do you have a specific example of how it doesn't work?

Comment: It may have something with your CSS. Can you post a http://jsfiddle.net or at least the relevant HTML and CSS in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I had concentrated into this problem for days, I just figured out that the problem was not on the `<fieldset>` tag, but on the `<label>` tag that is within it.

Basically, I `styled` the `<label>` tag as such and the issue went away.

```
<fieldset style="width:29%;float:left">         
    <label style="width:96%">Imagem</label>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('main_image', array('type' => 'file','label'=>FALSE,'style'=>'120px')); ?>
</fieldset>
```

[image]

Now for this specific case, the `<label>` tag and its content is forced to fit within 96% of the size of `<fieldset>` not matter what it is, and since `<fieldset>` is floating left, anymore `<fieldset>` that floats left and whose width is less that the difference of this and 100% will fit on the same level, which was my goal.

Apparently, Firefox wasnt forcing the `<label>` tag to obey its parent, the `<fieldset>` tag. Instead it was forcing `<fieldset>` to fit around `<label>`. Perhaps `<label>` is style somewhere in my `css` that I dont know.

Thanks to all who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

> When you give an element a width of 100% in CSS, you’re basically
>   saying “Make this element’s content area exactly equal to the explicit
>   width of its parent — but only if its parent has an explicit width.”

That means if your parent container's width has not been set explicitly, i.e. `width:400px` then it should not work as expected (different browsers behave differently), because `values set in Percentage` of a child element first calculates the dimension of the parent container and then the child element apply it's dimension, say width.

[**You can read this**](http://www.impressivewebs.com/width-100-percent-css/).

Also you can use [**css reset**](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to make the css consistent for all browsers.